# unexpected behaviour of override with Kotlin class delegation

Tags: kotlin, delegation

From what I understand, class delegation is supposed to

> allow object composition to achieve the same code reuse as
>   inheritance. [[wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Kotlin supports Class Delegation, and note the following statement form the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html):

> overrides work as you might expect: The compiler will use your
>   override implementations instead of those in the delegate object.

With this in mind, consider the following minimal example:

```
interface A {
  val v: String

  fun printV() {
    Logger.getLogger().info(Logger.APP, "A", v)
  }
}

class AImpl : A {
  override val v = "A"
}

class B(a: A) : A by a {
  override val v: String = "B"
}
```

I expected that `B(AImpl()).printV()` would print `B`, however instead it prints `A`, i.e. it uses the default implementation of `AImpl`.

Moreover, if I override the `printV()` Method in B using the `super` implementation, i.e.

```
class B(a: A) : A by a {
  override val v: String = "B"
  override fun printV() {
    super.printV()
  }
}
```

I now expected that `B(AImpl()).printV()` would print `A`, however this time it prints `B`.
This seems counterintuitive.

Can you give a good explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works as expected.

> I expected that B(AImpl()).printV() would print B, however instead it
>   prints A, i.e. it uses the default implementation of AImpl.

Always imagine class delegation, as you would redirect the call to the delegation class by yourself:

```
class B(private val a: A) : A {
    override val v: String = "B"

    override fun printV() {
        a.printV()
    }
}
```

This makes clear, that a call to `printV` is just delegated to `a` and it doesn't really matter what the value of `v` is in the class `B`.

---

> Moreover, if I override the printV() Method in B using the super
>   implementation, i.e.
>   I now expected that B(AImpl()).printV() would print A, however this
>   time it prints B. This seems counterintuitive.

Again, imagine how the delegation works internally:

```
class B(private val a: A) : A {
    override val v: String = "B"

    override fun printV() {
        super.printV() // the super call than uses the overridden v
    }
}
```

This makes clear, that `a` is not longer involved and `printV` uses your local overridden variable.

**Update 1 (elaboration on second part)**

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

> The Delegation pattern has proven to be a good alternative to
>   implementation inheritance

So you must not see delegation as inheritance. It is delegation (look up wikipedia for the delegation pattern)

> ... and the compiler will generate all the methods of Base that forward to b.

So all the methods of your interface (`v`-property and `printV`) are just generated and forwarded to the delegation class.

Here the code snippets of the class `B` and the decompiled code to see how it works internally:

```
class B(a: A) : A by a {
    override val v: String = "B"
}
class C(a: A) : A by a {
    override val v: String = "B"
    override fun printV() {
        super.printV()
    }
}

public final class B implements A {
  @NotNull
  private final String v = "B";

  public B(@NotNull A a) {
    this.$$delegate_0 = a;
    this.v = "B"; 
  } 

  @NotNull
  public String getV() { return this.v; }

  public void printV() {
    this.$$delegate_0.printV();
  }
}

public final class C implements A {
  @NotNull
  private final String v = "B";

  public C(@NotNull A a) {
    this.$$delegate_0 = a;
  }

  @NotNull
  public String getV() {
    return this.v;
  }

  /*This more or less means super.printV() */
  public void printV() { A.DefaultImpls.printV(this); }
}
```

Comment: You finished the answer after I just finish my first two sentence. =p If you use `this::class` instead of v, the first one will be `AImpl` and the second one will be `B`

Comment: I'm still unsure, If I understand it properly - I would have expected the delegation to be more inheritance-like. Could you elaborate on the second part regarding super a bit more?